# handsontable doesn't work with IE and Chrome

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, handsontable

I'm new in Handsontable, very new, sorry.

I have to fix a bug and I don't know how to do it.

I'm using below codes:

```
$('#tableDiv').on('click', 'td input.htCheckboxRendererInput', function (event) {
    console.log("chosen a row");
    var selection = $("#tableDiv").handsontable('getInstance').getSelected();

    $.each($( this ).closest('td').siblings('td'), function(){
        console.log($(this).text());    
    });
    var indice=$( this ).closest('td').siblings('th').text();
    console.log("indice della riga:"+indice);
    console.log(TABLE_DATA[indice-1]);
    TABLE_DATA_PROMOTE.push(TABLE_DATA[indice-1]);
});
```

This works in Firefox, but not in IE and Chrome.

Could anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: add some example code of your problem , for example add a jsfiddle link with your example codes .

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what the issue is, I suggest using the [events provided by Handsontable](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/wiki/Events). In particular, you're looking for:

```
afterSelection (r: Number, c: Number, r2: Number, c2: Number)
```

Callback fired while one or more cells are being selected (on mouse move). Parameters:

```
r selection start row
c selection start column
r2 selection end row
c2 selection end column
```

You can easily see that this could be used to replicate your code. Note that `r2` and `c2` are different from `r` and `c` if you select more than one cell at a time, something that in your case I think is irrelevant.